# Bonnie test gives variable results

Tags: embedded-linux, stress-testing, embedded

When I run bonnie test on my embedded device the results are variable between the runs. My question is how can I reduce this variability?

Comment: Any other suggestions ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a benchmark, it's going to vary a little bit. Make sure that nothing I/O intensive is running. Since it's an embedded device, little actions are going to have a big impact. Make sure no jobs are running, no users (i.e. yourself) are doing ANYTHING, and that everything currently running ACTUALLY NEEDS TO BE RUNNING.

Also, if you have swap turned on (not sure why you would on an embedded device), turn it off.

Finally, linux keeps buffers and caches in memory to speed up disk access. Normally something like bonnie isn't very affected by this because it writes a HUGE amount of data (minimizing the impact of the buffers and cache). HOWEVER, if you want to be super paranoid you CAN clear these buffers and caches like this:

```
$> sync
$> echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I turn off swap ?

Comment: To see active swap: `cat /proc/swaps`. To turn it off: `swapoff /dev/swapdevice`